# SpringMVC Create Form in Controller

Tags: html, forms, spring-mvc

I'm using SpringMVC and wonderingn if it is posible to create form in Controller. What I have in mind is to create a form in Controller layer then pass it to View via `${form}` or anything like that then the `<form>` will automatically displayed in the View.

If you don't understand what I meant or any questions, feel free to comment. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: cause I need to create a form with `<select>` and dynamic options value from DAO.

Comment: Why not put those values in model attributes and use them in a JSP or other template?

Comment: Actually I know other ways to achieve what I wanted but if there is a way to make this happen, I want to know it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as what you describe. Create a `String`

```
String form = "<form> ... </form>";
```

Add it to model/request attributes

```
model.addAttribute("form", form);
```

And use it anywhere in your JSP (or other view) by retrieving it from the request attributes.

```
${form}
```

Comment: this is a great idea but what I expect is like `new Form()` then `form.addOption()`. something like that,.

Comment: @kenicky Spring doesn't provide such built in functionality. I really suggest using a JSP view or some other templating languages. You can make the form generation be part of one file and import it everywhere else.

Comment: Ohh so, Spring doesn't provide that. Thanks for the answer man.